# Problems installing Ubuntu on imac

Tags: boot, system-installation

I want to run Ubuntu on an old imac 7.1. I used my Windows-PC with balena-Etcher to flash a hdd and I put it in the imac.
I get this error message:

"the efi file system creation in partition failed"

As I boot from a hard drive, I cannot change the usb port, as suggested in other posts. Waht should I do now?